# How do I bind a text box to a structure element?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, structure

I would like to bind the text field of a textbox to an element in an instance of a structure that I've created in a class module.  When I try to create a Data Source using an OBJECT type, all I see in the tree is the name of the structure, not the instance I've created.  If I select the structure anyway, the Data Sources tree does show the name of the structure and the element I'm interested in.  How do I bind to a specific instance?  I'm using VB.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assign instance programmatically to datasource , it will not available in design time, you can do it in formload or any other event.

```
   something like..
   BindingSource.Datasource = new instance //assign to your instance to binding source
   then..
   TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", BindingSource, "Name", True))// here name propery is binding to textbox
```

Comment: Thanks for both the explanation and the solution.  Seems obvious now.

Comment: Well ... Not quite.  I can't set the Datasource to NEW instance since the structure I'm trying to bind to already exists, and is full of data.  More importantly, although the value in my structure does show up in the textbox when my form loads, as I change the data in my structure, the textbox.text does not change.

Comment: Looks like I need to put code into the Set portion of my structure that raises the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: can you post your code? I think its minor mistake somewhere, otherwise it would have work fine. And I hope you have assigned instance is class level?